# correct code for sending an email, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have a form that allows a user to send an email to everyone on a mailing list (linq table). I'm having trouble with the correct code and syntax for linking to the smtp server.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;



public partial class MassEmail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mailingListClassDataContext Class = new mailingListClassDataContext();
        var emaillist = from emails in Class.mailinglistMembers select emails.email;

        foreach (var subcriber in emaillist)
        {


                MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
                objMail.From = "test@test.com";

                objMail.To = subcriber;

                objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html ;


                //The subject of the message 
                objMail.Subject = "test email that i hope works" ;

                //he message text 
                objMail.Body = Editor1.Content;

                //need help in this area
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                SmtpClient.Send(objMail);

                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var db = new mailingListClassDataContext())
{
    var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

    var recipients = from e in db.mailinglistMembers
                     select e.email;

    foreach (string recipient in recipients)
    {
        var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("sender@example.com", recipient);
        message.Subject = "Hello World!";
        message.Body = "<h1>Foo bar</h1>";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Try setting up configuration in your *web.config* or *machine.config*. Make sure you've specified the correct address and port of the SMTP server.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="me@example.com">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks! maybe you can help me out with my other pending question, titled: "delete record onClick, asp.net"

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to put the smtp server details in your web.config

```
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp>
                <network
                   host="smtp.emailhost.com"
                   port="25"
                   userName="username"
                   password="password" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
  <system.web>
```

Comment: Or better; in `machine.config`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the SMTP server IP or name in the constructor to SmtpClient or set it explicity through the Host property.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the `Host` (and possibly the `Credentials`) property on the [`SmptClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx). The server (host) defaults to localhost.
Also consider creating the `client` instance outside of the loop.